# MODULE FAILURE while using 'become' in ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I want to run a specific Ansible task as a different user(webadmin) than the one who connect to the remote machine(root). Therefore, I use 'become' module to change the user in my task:

```html
---
- name: Git clone
  git:
    repo: '{{ repository }}'
    dest: '{{ workcopypath }}/{{ project_group }}'
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ myuser }}'
```

However, there are something wrong while I running my playbook:

```html
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/source_control/git.py
<10.122.2.20> cmd|/bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781="` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781 `" ) && sleep 0'|False|None
<10.122.2.20> put_file|/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-13654yyClbh/tmpTL422C|/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781/git.py
<10.122.2.20> cmd|/bin/sh -c 'setfacl -m u:webadmin:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781/git.py && sleep 0'|False|None
<10.122.2.20> cmd|/bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u webadmin /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ozfqbfexlaybkeimxrmuyppdrzmrhxxu; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781/git.py'"'"' && sleep 0'|True|None
<10.122.2.20> cmd|/bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'|False|Non

fatal: [10.122.2.20]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "", 
    "module_stdout": "ERROR: invalid timeout value of BECOME-SUCCESS-ozfqbfexlaybkeimxrmuyppdrzmrhxxu\n/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542694736.75-69768062845781/git.py\"' && sleep 0'': [Errno 2] No such file or directory", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 512
}
```

I have set free secret in remote machine while using git clone/pull/push... under the user webadmin. I don't know how to fix this problem, is there anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file on the remote system, so that there is the following line:

```
ANSIBLE_SSH_USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

You can test it with:

```
your_user@ansible-server:~$ ssh ANSIBLE_SSH_USER@remote_system "sudo -H -S -n -u webadmin /bin/sh -c /bin/uname"
```

This should return `Linux` or whatever your remote system is. If there is something with `sudo: a password is required` then you `/etc/sudoers` is still not fine. If it works, try it with you ansible script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[JGK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6561343/jgk) feedback.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/53401098/686105

I also write this sample playbook to check `become_user` method.

### Playbook

```yaml
---

- name: Check become_user of postgres
  hosts: server
  tasks:

    - name: Run with root.
      command: whoami
      become: true
      register: root_rc

    - name: Run with postgres.
      command: whoami
      become: true
      become_user: postgres
      register: postgres_rc

    - name: print result
      debug:
        msg: "[ root_rc: {{ root_rc.stdout }}, postgres_rc: {{ postgres_rc.stdout }}]"
```

### Run before change: FAILED

```
[ chusiang@banshee ~/playbooks ] - 17:33
ssh server "sudo -H -S -n -u postgres /bin/sh -c /bin/uname"
sudo: a password is required
```

```
[ chusiang@banshee ~/playbooks ] - 17:35
(cmd)$ ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=0 ansible-playbook check_become_user.yml
 ______________________________________
< PLAY [Check become_user of postgres] >
 --------------------------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

 ________________________
< TASK [Gathering Facts] >
 ------------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

ok: [server]
 _______________________
< TASK [Run with root.] >
 -----------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

changed: [server]
 ___________________________
< TASK [Run with postgres.] >
 ---------------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "rc": 1
}

MSG:

MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error
 ____________
< PLAY RECAP >
 ------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

server                    : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

### Add sudo no password setting of postgres

**Please replace the username of `chusiang` to yourself.**

```
 [root@server ~]# sudo vim /etc/sudoers.d/postgres

+ chusiang ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

### Run after change: PASS

```
[ chusiang@banshee ~/playbooks ] - 17:35
ssh server "sudo -H -S -n -u postgres /bin/sh -c /bin/uname"
Linux
```

```
[ jonny@banshee ~/vcs/lw/jonny.lai/lw-cloud.ansible.M2 ] (feature/support_only_offic) - 17:36
(cmd)$ ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=0 ansible-playbook check_become_user.yml
 ______________________________________
< PLAY [Check become_user of postgres] >
 --------------------------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

 ________________________
< TASK [Gathering Facts] >
 ------------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

ok: [server]
 _______________________
< TASK [Run with root.] >
 -----------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

changed: [server]
 ___________________________
< TASK [Run with postgres.] >
 ---------------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

changed: [server]
 _____________________
< TASK [print result] >
 ---------------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

ok: [server] => {}

MSG:

[ root_rc: root, postgres_rc: postgres]
 ____________
< PLAY RECAP >
 ------------
  \
   \   \_\_    _/_/
    \      \__/
           (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||

server                    : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```